SocialLoginView error -> DJango - dj_rest_auth
def google_callback(request):
    client_id = settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
    client_secret = settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_SECRET
    code = request.GET.get('code')
    """
    Access Token Request
    """
    token_req = requests.post(
        f"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&code={code}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri={GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URI}&state={state}")
    token_req_json = token_req.json()
    print(token_req_json)
    error = token_req_json.get("error")
    if error is not None:
        raise JSONDecodeError(error)
    access_token = token_req_json.get('access_token')

    """
    Email Request
    """
    email_req = requests.get(
        f"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={access_token}")
    email_req_status = email_req.status_code
    if email_req_status != 200:
        return JsonResponse({'err_msg': 'failed to get email'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    email_req_json = email_req.json()
    email = email_req_json.get('email')
    """
    Signup or Signin Request
    """
    print(access_token)
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)

        # 기존에 가입된 유저의 Provider가 google이 아니면 에러 발생, 맞으면 로그인
        # 다른 SNS로 가입된 유저
        social_user = SocialAccount.objects.get(user=user)
        if social_user is None:
            return JsonResponse({'err_msg': 'email exists but not social user'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        if social_user.provider != 'google':
            return JsonResponse({'err_msg': 'no matching social type'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        # 기존에 Google로 가입된 유저
        data = {'access_token': access_token, 'code': code}
        print(data)
        accept = requests.post(
            f"{BASE_URL}accounts/google/login/finish/", data=data)
        accept_status = accept.status_code
        if accept_status != 200:
            return JsonResponse({'err_msg': 'failed to signin'}, status=accept_status)
        accept_json = accept.json()
        accept_json.pop('user', None)
        return JsonResponse(accept_json)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        # 기존에 가입된 유저가 없으면 새로 가입
        data = {'access_token': access_token, 'code': code}
        accept = requests.post(
            f"{BASE_URL}accounts/google/login/finish/", data=data)
        accept_status = accept.status_code
        if accept_status != 200:
            return JsonResponse({'err_msg': 'failed to signup'}, status=accept_status)
        accept_json = accept.json()
        accept_json.pop('user', None)
        return JsonResponse(accept_json)


class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = google_view.GoogleOAuth2Adapter
    callback_url = GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URI
    client_class = OAuth2Client

=> this code dose not work...
Access tokens and emails are perfectly received. However, the error below continues to occur in the "/accounts/google/login/finish/" section.
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
[23/Jul/2024 12:35:15] "POST /accounts/google/login/finish/ HTTP/1.1" 500 149224
Internal Server Error: /accounts/google/callback/
[23/Jul/2024 12:35:15] "GET /accounts/google/callback/?code=4/0AcvDMrD4REcodecodeunfVPnlaMZ2do8mg&scope=email%2d%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&authuser=1&prompt=consent HTTP/1.1" 500 31
Please help.. I haven't been able to solve it for a long time.
Parsing and code modification to solve numerous json problems..
